# ¿Cómo hacer un elemento de lista plegable?

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero crear una vista de lista expandible. En mi caso para que pueda ver todos los estudiantes puntajes de prueba.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente lo siguiente:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

 <p>
       <label>Text box</label>
       <input type="Search for names" id="myInput" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="Search for names..">
 </p>

 <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Collapsible</button>

 <div id="textOutCollapsible" class="collapse">
 Lorem ipsum dolor text....
 </div>
 <p id="txtOut">

 </p>
</body>

<script>
fetch('https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/students')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    var divOut = document.getElementById('txtOut');
    var divOutCollapsible = document.getElementById('textOutCollapsible');
    var allStudents = myJson.students;
    for (var k in allStudents) {
      let txtOut = '';
      let listItem = document.createElement('li');
      let values = allStudents[k].grades;
      let sum = values.reduce((previous, current) => current += previous);
      let avg = sum / values.length;

      // we add the name as part of the dataset
      listItem.dataset.nombre = allStudents[k].firstName.toUpperCase();

      txtOut += `<b>${allStudents[k].firstName}</b><br />`;
      txtOut += `email: ${allStudents[k].email}<br />`;
      txtOut += `Company: ${allStudents[k].company}<br />`;
      txtOut += `Skill: ${allStudents[k].skill}<br />`;
      txtOut += `Average: ${avg}<br />`;
      txtOut += `<img src="${allStudents[k].pic}"><hr />`;
      textOutCollapsible += `Average: ${allStudents[k].grades}<br />`;

      listItem.innerHTML = txtOut, textOutCollapsible;
      divOut.appendChild(listItem);
      divOutCollapsible.appendChild(listItem);
    }
  });

function search() {
  // Declare variables
  const prefix = document.getElementById( 'myInput' ).value.toUpperCase( );
  const ul = document.getElementById( 'txtOut' );
  const childs = ul.getElementsByTagName( 'li' );
  var idx = -1, item;

  while(item = childs.item(++idx)){
   item.style.display = item.dataset['nombre'].startsWith(prefix) ? 'initial': 'none';
  }
}

var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
</script>
</html>
```

Pero solo me da un button en alto.
Además intenté calcular la media `average` para cada estudiantes y mostrar los detalles cuandos presiona el botón en forma de cruz pero me da números un poco demasiado grandes para parecer verdaderos. Aqui esta una imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si tienen ideas sobre como reproducir el CSS estoy interesado :)

## Actualizacion

Intenté la respuesta de Byro :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>
    <label>Text box</label>
    <input type="Search for names" id="myInput" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="Search for names..">
</p>
<p>
    <label>Tag box</label>
    <input type="Search for tags" id="myInput" onkeyup="searchTag()" placeholder="Search for tags..">
</p>
<div class="box">
    <div class="header-box" id="header-box-2">
        More visible content
        <span class="btn" id="btn-expand-box-2" onclick="swap(this)">Show more...</span>
    </div>
    <div class="expandable hidden" id="expandable-box-2">
        <ul id="txtOut">
            <li>22</li>
            <li>88</li>
            <li>66</li>
            <li id="avg"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="header-box" id="header-box-2">
        More visible content
        <span class="btn" id="btn-expand-box-2" onclick="swap(this)">Show more...</span>
    </div>
    <div class="expandable hidden" id="expandable-box-2">
        <ul id="txtOut">
            <li>55</li>
            <li>14</li>
            <li>12</li>
            <li id="avg"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


</body>

<script>
fetch( 'https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/students' )
  .then( function( response ) {
    return response.json( );
  } )
  .then( function( myJson ) {
    const divOut = document.getElementById( 'txtOut' );
    var allStudents = myJson.students;
    for( let k in allStudents ) {
      let txtOut = '';
      let listItem = document.createElement( 'li' );
      let grades =  `${allStudents[k].grades}`;
      //let sum = values.reduce((previous, current) => current += previous);
      //let avg = sum / values.length;

      // Añadimos el nombre como parte del dataset.
      listItem.dataset.nombre = allStudents[k].firstName.toUpperCase( );

      txtOut += `<b>${allStudents[k].firstName}</b><br />`;
      txtOut += `email: ${allStudents[k].email}<br />`;
      txtOut += `Company: ${allStudents[k].company}<br />`;
      txtOut += `Skill: ${allStudents[k].skill}<br />`;
      //txtOut += `Average: ${avg}<br />`;
      txtOut += `Grades: ${allStudents[k].grades}<br />`;
      txtOut += `<img src="${allStudents[k].pic}"><hr />`;

      listItem.innerHTML = txtOut;
      divOut.appendChild( listItem );
    }
  } );

function search() {
  const prefix = document.getElementById( 'myInput' ).value.toUpperCase( );
  const ul = document.getElementById( 'txtOut' );
  const childs = ul.getElementsByTagName( 'li' );
  var idx = -1, item;

  while( item = childs.item( ++idx ) ) {
//        console.log( typeof( item.dataset.nombre ), item.dataset.nombre );
    item.style.display = item.dataset['nombre'].startsWith( prefix ) ? 'initial' : 
'none';
  }
}

function searchTag() {
  const prefix = document.getElementById( 'myInput' ).value.toUpperCase( );
  const ul = document.getElementById( 'txtOut' );
  const childs = ul.getElementsByTagName( 'li' );
  var idx = -1, item;

  while( item = childs.item( ++idx ) ) {
//        console.log( typeof( item.dataset.nombre ), item.dataset.nombre );
    item.style.display = item.dataset['nombre'].startsWith( prefix ) ? 'initial' : 
'none';
  }
}

function swap(e) {
 // variables
 let sum, avg,li=[];
 // creamos un arreglo text
    let text = ["Show more...", "Hide text..."];
    // validamos que el texto del elemento clickeado sea igual al primer elemento del text
    // si lo es le cambiamos el texto a text[1] o lo cambiamos a text[0] en caso contrario
    e.textContent = text[e.textContent == text[0] ? 1 : 0];
    box = e.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("#expandable-box-2");

    // con  el metodo toggle agregamos la clase si existe o la ocultamos si no
    box.classList.toggle("hidden");
    // validamos que el campo average alla sido calculado anteriormente
    if(box.querySelector("#avg").innerText !="") return;

    // recorremos todos los li atravez de un forEach 
    box.querySelectorAll("li").forEach((el)=>{
     // validamos que se pueda comvertir el texto a entero y lo agregamos al arreglo li
     if(parseInt(el.innerText)) li.push(parseInt(el.innerText));
    });

    // calcular el avg:
    // validamos que existe por lo minimo un elemento en li
    if (li.length){
     // sumamos todos lo valores de li
     sum = li.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; });
     // calculamos el avg y con toFixed obtenemos solo 2 decimales
     avg = (sum / li.length).toFixed(2);
     // agregar a box el texto);
  box.querySelector("#avg").innerText = `El avg es ${avg}`;
 }
}

</script>
</html>

<head>
<style>
body {
        padding: 5% 8%;
    }
    .header-box {
        border       : 1px solid grey;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding      : 1em;
    }
    .header-box-active {
        border-bottom-left-radius : 0;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    }
    .btn {
        background   : lightgrey;
        border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
        cursor       : pointer;
        float        : right;
        margin       : -1em;
        padding      : 1rem;
    }
    .box {
        padding      : 2em;
    }
    .expandable {
        border       : 1px solid grey;
        border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
        border-top   : 0;
        padding      : 1em;
    }
    .hidden {
        display      : none;
    }
    .btn-contract-active {
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    }
    .visible {
        display      : block;
    }
</style>
</head>
```

Pero el botón aparece afuera.

**Parece que es posible hacerlo con un framework. Pero no conozco nada de estos**

Comment: no entiendo muy bien lo que intentas... podrias incluir solo el html y el css y decir que deseas hacer solamente!

Answer (score 0):

Una posibilidad **si quieres usar javascript** es **intercambiar una clase CSS (añadirla / quitarla)**:

```js
    function $(id)
        {
            return document.getElementById(id);
        }

        function swap(id_clicked_element)
    {
        if (id_clicked_element == "box-1") {
            $("expandable-box-1").classList.toggle("visible");
            $("header-box-1").classList.toggle("header-box-active");
            $("btn-expand-box-1").classList.toggle("hidden");
            $("btn-contract-box-1").classList.toggle("visible");
            $("btn-contract-box-1").classList.toggle("no-radius-buttom-right");
            $("btn-contract-box-1").classList.toggle("btn-contract-active");
        }

        if (id_clicked_element == "box-2") {
            $("expandable-box-2").classList.toggle("visible");
            $("header-box-2").classList.toggle("header-box-active");
            $("btn-expand-box-2").classList.toggle("hidden");
            $("btn-contract-box-2").classList.toggle("visible");
            $("btn-contract-box-2").classList.toggle("no-radius-buttom-right");
            $("btn-contract-box-2").classList.toggle("btn-contract-active");
        }
    }
```

```css
        body {
            padding: 5% 8%;
        }
        .header-box {
            border       : 1px solid grey;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding      : 1em;
        }
        .header-box-active {
            border-bottom-left-radius : 0;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
        }
        .btn {
            background   : lightgrey;
            border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
            cursor       : pointer;
            float        : right;
            margin       : -1em;
            padding      : 1rem;
        }
        .box {
            padding      : 2em;
        }
        .expandable {
            border       : 1px solid grey;
            border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
            border-top   : 0;
            padding      : 1em;
        }
        .hidden {
            display      : none;
        }
        .btn-contract-active {
            border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
        }
        .visible {
            display      : block;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- This is the box 1 -->
<div class="box">
    <div class="header-box" id="header-box-1">
        Visible content
        <span class="btn"        id="btn-expand-box-1"   onclick="swap('box-1')">Show more...</span>
        <span class="btn hidden" id="btn-contract-box-1" onclick="swap('box-1')">Hide text...</span>
    </div>
    <div class="expandable hidden" id="expandable-box-1">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia velit odit fugiat quidem distinctio aliquid corporis repellat quisquam praesentium explicabo, provident est asperiores dicta, saepe unde quibusdam quam, totam illum.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- This is the box 2 -->
<div class="box">
    <div class="header-box" id="header-box-2">
        More visible content
        <span class="btn"        id="btn-expand-box-2"   onclick="swap('box-2')">Show more...</span>
        <span class="btn hidden" id="btn-contract-box-2" onclick="swap('box-2')">Hide text...</span>
    </div>
    <div class="expandable hidden" id="expandable-box-2">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam pariatur vitae, soluta voluptatem excepturi voluptates necessitatibus alias porro aspernatur quam tenetur quidem magni quasi fuga nobis molestias recusandae laudantium quaerat.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum eius suscipit vero eum ad unde soluta minima dolorem facilis tempora eligendi obcaecati sunt.</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Para hacerlo con CSS**, el truco consiste en **usar checks ocultos cuyo estado (chequeado o no) afectarán a los estilos de los elementos que queremos controlar**. Los elementos que vamos a cambiar deben estar al mismo nivel que el check y después de este.

```css
        body {
            font-size: 1rem;
            padding: 5% 20%;
        }

        /*** CSS to expand contents ***/
        #check-expand-box-1:checked~#expandable-box-1,
        #check-expand-box-2:checked~#expandable-box-2 {
            display: block !important;
        }
        #check-expand-box-1:checked~#title-box-1,
        #check-expand-box-2:checked~#title-box-2 {
            color: blue !important;
        }
        #check-expand-box-1:checked~#btn-expand-box-1,
        #check-expand-box-2:checked~#btn-expand-box-2 {
            display: none !important;
        }
        #check-expand-box-1:checked~#btn-contract-box-1,
        #check-expand-box-2:checked~#btn-contract-box-2 {
            display: block !important;
        }


        .header-box {
            border       : 1px solid grey;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding      : 1rem;
        }
        .btn,
        .title {
            position: relative;
            left: 1rem;
            top: -2.2rem;
        }
        .btn {
            background   : lightgrey;
            border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
            cursor       : pointer;
            float        : right;
            margin-right : 1.05rem;
            padding      : 1rem;
            top          : -3.3rem;
        }
        .box {
            padding      : 2em;
        }
        .expandable {
            border       : 1px solid grey;
            border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
            border-top   : 0;
            margin-top   : -1.38rem; /* HACK: to hide top div border-radius */
            padding      : 1em;
        }
        .hidden {
            display      : none;
        }
        .visible {
            display      : block;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- This is the box 1 -->
    <div class="box">
        <div class="header-box" id="header-box-1">
            &nbsp;
        </div>

        <input type="checkbox" id="check-expand-box-1" class="hidden">
        <span class="title" id="title-box-1">Visible content</span>
        <label class="btn" id="btn-expand-box-1" for="check-expand-box-1">More text...</label>
        <label class="btn hidden" id="btn-contract-box-1" for="check-expand-box-1">Hide text...</label>

        <div class="expandable hidden" id="expandable-box-1">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia velit odit fugiat quidem distinctio aliquid corporis repellat quisquam praesentium explicabo, provident est asperiores dicta, saepe unde quibusdam quam, totam illum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- This is the box 2 -->
    <div class="box">
        <div class="header-box" id="header-box-2">
            &nbsp;
        </div>

        <input type="checkbox" id="check-expand-box-2" class="hidden">
        <span class="title" id="title-box-2">More visible content</span>
        <label class="btn" id="btn-expand-box-2" for="check-expand-box-2">More text...</label>
        <label class="btn hidden" id="btn-contract-box-2" for="check-expand-box-2">Hide text...</label>

        <div class="expandable hidden" id="expandable-box-2">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia velit odit fugiat quidem distinctio aliquid corporis.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Pero, ¿cómo puedo hacerlo para cada alumno? ¿Para cada artículo en mi lista? Soy nuevo en javascript y no sé si tengo que puestarlo entre los `<p>` o los `<div>`

Comment: Te acabo de añadir una segunda caja, si hay más el procedimiento es el mismo. También se podría hacer solo con CSS.

Comment: Si, he visto. Gracias por la ayuda. Sin embargo ya no puedo ver el contenido. No puedo mostrar a mis alumnos en estas cajas que colapsan.

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que lo que buscas es algo como esto:

```js
    function swap(e) {
     // variables
     let sum, avg,li=[];
     // creamos un arreglo text
        let text = ["Show more...", "Hide text..."];
        // validamos que el texto del elemento clickeado sea igual al primer elemento del text
        // si lo es le cambiamos el texto a text[1] o lo cambiamos a text[0] en caso contrario
        e.textContent = text[e.textContent == text[0] ? 1 : 0];
        box = e.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("#expandable-box-2");

        // con  el metodo toggle agregamos la clase si existe o la ocultamos si no
        box.classList.toggle("hidden");
    // validamos que el campo average alla sido calculado anteriormente
    if(box.querySelector("#avg").innerText !="") return;

    // recorremos todos los li atravez de un forEach 
    box.querySelectorAll("li").forEach((el)=>{
     // validamos que se pueda comvertir el texto a entero y lo agregamos al arreglo li
     if(parseInt(el.innerText)) li.push(parseInt(el.innerText));
    });

    // calcular el avg:
    // validamos que existe por lo minimo un elemento en li
    if (li.length){
     // sumamos todos lo valores de li
     sum = li.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; });
     // calculamos el avg y con toFixed obtenemos solo 2 decimales
     avg = (sum / li.length).toFixed(2);
     // agregar a box el texto);
  box.querySelector("#avg").innerText = `El avg es ${avg}`;
 }
    }
```

```css
.header-box {
        border       : 1px solid grey;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding      : 1em;
    }
    .header-box-active {
        border-bottom-left-radius : 0;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    }
    .btn {
        background   : lightgrey;
        border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
        cursor       : pointer;
        float        : right;
        margin       : -1em;
        padding      : 1rem;
    }
    .box {
        padding      : 2em;
    }
    .expandable {
        border       : 1px solid grey;
        border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
        border-top   : 0;
        padding      : 1em;
    }
    .hidden {
        display      : none;
    }
    .btn-contract-active {
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    }
    .visible {
        display      : block;
    }
```

```html
<p>
    <label>Text box</label>
    <input type="Search for names" id="myInput" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="Search for names..">
</p>
<p>
    <label>Tag box</label>
    <input type="Search for tags" id="myInput" onkeyup="searchTag()" placeholder="Search for tags..">
</p>
<div class="box">
    <div class="header-box" id="header-box-2">
        More visible content
        <span class="btn" id="btn-expand-box-2" onclick="swap(this)">Show more...</span>
    </div>
    <div class="expandable hidden" id="expandable-box-2">
        <ul id="txtOut">
            <li>22</li>
            <li>88</li>
            <li>66</li>
            <li id="avg"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="header-box" id="header-box-2">
        More visible content
        <span class="btn" id="btn-expand-box-2" onclick="swap(this)">Show more...</span>
    </div>
    <div class="expandable hidden" id="expandable-box-2">
        <ul id="txtOut">
            <li>55</li>
            <li>14</li>
            <li>12</li>
            <li id="avg"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**actualizacion de pregunta:**

```js
var $ = s =>document.querySelector(s);


fetch('https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/students')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
 let txtOut = '';
 let wraper = $('#wraper');

    var allStudents = myJson.students;
    for (var k in allStudents) {
      let values = allStudents[k].grades;
      let sum = values.reduce((previous, current) => parseInt(current) + parseInt(previous));
      let avg = (sum / values.length).toFixed(2);           

  txtOut += `<div class="box">
        <div class="header-box" id="header-box-2">
           <img src="${allStudents[k].pic}"> <span class="btn" id="btn-expand-box-2" onclick="swap(this)">➕</span>
           <b>${allStudents[k].firstName.toUpperCase()}</b><br />
          email: ${allStudents[k].email}<br />
          Company: ${allStudents[k].company}<br />
          Skill: ${allStudents[k].skill}<br />
          Average: ${avg}<br /></div>
        <div class="expandable hidden" id="expandable-box-2"><ul id="txtOut">`;

  for(let x in allStudents[k].grades) txtOut += `<li>test ${x}: ${allStudents[k].grades[x]}</li>`;

  txtOut += `</ul></div></div>`;
    }
    wraper.innerHTML = txtOut;
  });

function swap(e) {
 // variables
 let sum, avg,li=[];
 // creamos un arreglo text
    let text = ["➕", "➖"];
    // validamos que el texto del elemento clickeado sea igual al primer elemento del text
    // si lo es le cambiamos el texto a text[1] o lo cambiamos a text[0] en caso contrario
    e.textContent = text[e.textContent == text[0] ? 1 : 0];
    box = e.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("#expandable-box-2");

    // con  el metodo toggle agregamos la clase si existe o la ocultamos si no
    box.classList.toggle("hidden");
}
```

```css
 .header-box {
        border       : 1px solid grey;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding      : 1em;
    }
    .header-box-active {
        border-bottom-left-radius : 0;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    }
    .btn {
        background   : lightgrey;
        border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
        cursor       : pointer;
        float        : right;
        margin       : -1em;
        padding      : 1rem;
    }

    .expandable {
        border       : 1px solid grey;
        border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
        border-top   : 0;
        padding      : 1em;
    }
    .hidden {
        display      : none;
    }
    .btn-contract-active {
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    }
    .visible {
        display      : block;
    }
    img {
   border-radius: 50%;
   border: 1px solid black;
 }
```

```html
<p>
<label>Text box</label>
<input type="Search for names" id="myInput" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="Search for names..">
</p>

<div id="wraper"></div>
```

Comment: Casi ! Solo tengo un problema: el botón está fuera de la lista. Actualicé mi pregunta con un intento con su respuesta.

Comment: @ThePassenger esta un poco complicado entender actulize mi respuesta! solo debes poner en tu pregunta `tengo esto` "tu codigo y una imagen previa" y espero  lograr `aquello` "imagen de como debe verse" y que debe hacer!